# Where is there a good introduction to hypercomplex numbers and calculus?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I'm looking for a good introduction to hypercomplex numbers that requires as little math knowledge as possible, yet covers hypercomplex numbers as thoroughly as possible.  I'm interested specifically in performing calculus over hypercomplex numbers, so I'm looking for something that really covers hypercomplex calculus.  I'm willing to learn a little extra math for the right book/paper/etc., but again, I'd prefer something that covers the hypercomplex calculus with as little foreknowledge as possible.

Is there a place or book, etc. that teaches this?

Answer (score 1):

Typing "[Hypercomplex calculus](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hypercomplex%20calculus&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb)" into Google yields the following result:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomplex_analysis